# What does the option " -q" in git cli and this command do?

Tags: linux, git, command-line

I'm learning for Machine Learning and I'm analyzing about Siam Mask Tutorial in google colab.

I saw the code "-q", I don't know what the code means.

I looked it up but couldn't find it.

I'd be very grateful if you could help me.

I think that the code is one of Linux command option

```sh
!git clone -q --depth 1 {git_repo_url}
!sed -i "/torch/d" {project_name}/requirements.txt
!cd {project_name} && pip install -q -r requirements.txt
!cd {project_name} && bash make.sh
!pip install -q youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is not about machine learning but clones a repository managed by the version control system git.

Git clone's help page tell you the `-q` option switches to quiet, as in non-verbous, command line output.

```
  git clone -?                                                                                                                                                                                
  usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  -v, --verbose         be more verbose                                                                                   
  -q, --quiet           be more quiet                                                                                     
  --progress            force progress reporting                                                                          
  -n, --no-checkout     don't create a checkout                                                                           
  --bare                create a bare repository                                                                          
  --mirror              create a mirror repository (implies bare)                                                         
  -l, --local           to clone from a local repository                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [...]
```

The second `-q` option in your example refers to `pip` becoming quit(er), as in less verbose, by reducing the loglevel with each `q` you add as a parameter (max. 3 are possible). This can be found by calling `pip install --help``` on your console. Excerpt:

```
-q, --quiet       Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
```

So, line by line your bash commands do the following:

1. clone repository to current prompt from `{git_repo_url}`
2. string operation in requirements.txt for dependency correction
3. change prompt to project directory and install all python dependencies of the project
4. change prompt to project directory and run the make script
5. install python package quietly

Generally for future reference: If you are unsure about what a command does, try using only that command with no parameters plus any variation of `-?`, `-h` or `--help`. On most unixoide shells this gives you a pretty helpful page of the command's purpose and all (or most) of its possible parameters. Make it a habit of always referring to this first, this is literally the developers themselves teaching you how to use their software.